# Help with SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which has among others a column called cust_name of type varchar(30). I want to retrieve a list of all the name which does not contain the letter 'P' in it. what is the query I should use?

Comment: I can't test it right now so here's a comment `SELECT C.cust_name
FROM CUSTOMER C
WHERE C.cust_name <> '%P%'`

Comment: @zerkms Could you explain why? Does the `NOT LIKE` belong to the SQL standard while the `<>` not?

Comment: @faif: `<>` doesn't deal with `%` as with wildcard. When you write `field <> '%P%'` mysql will look for the fields that **exactly** do not equal to `%P%` string.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT C.cust_name
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.cust_name NOT LIKE '%P%'
```